# Alternative to spacedesk

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, duplicate-display

Goal: extending the screen of a laptop on another laptop.

I'm looking for an alternative free software to spacedesk in order to connect two laptops (the first one with windows 10, the second one with windows 7).

So far I found deskreen, but it requires a HDMI dummy plug.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Especially missing: what features do you need, how much may it cost? And btw, I'm using Deskreen. It also works without a HDMI dummy – you then just cannot use it to *extend* your desktop.

Comment: Ah, so it's about extending the desktop. What's the problem with the HDMI dummy? Btw, I'm using Deskreen with a Displayport dummy (works fine), and there are also dummies for DVI and VGA. Coming around 5-6 bucks, they are quite affordable.

Comment: @Izzy I prefer to avoid to buy a HDMI dummy

Comment: I've read it can be done software-based, but that would require quite a lot of effort. And not sure about Windows, as that was said about Linux. You could try finding a solution to emulate a monitor via software, so that emulated monitor could be used by Deskreen. Maybe [this approach on our sister site](https://superuser.com/q/62051/143340) can help you with that? No additional soft- or hardware needed.

Answer (score 1):

My go-to recommendation for that kind of use case is [barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier) - which is an open-source fork of Synergy.
Barrier allows you to drive two computers from one keyboard/mouse set. I highly encourage you to test it.

Comment: Hello @Riduidel thank you for your answer. My goal is not to control 2 laptops with a single keyboard and a single mouse (like the software mouse without borders), but to extend the screen of one laptop on the other one